# Regex capture iterator method moves iterator

Tags: regex, iterator, rust, borrow-checker

I am processing simple strings of the format "1s:1d", "100:5000", etc with this regex:

```
let retention_matcher = regex::Regex::new({r"^(\d+)([smhdy])?:(\d+)([smhdy])?$"}).unwrap();
```

I know this regex should only match once so I want to run the regex for captures and check the number of captures.

```
    let iter = retention_matcher.captures_iter(ts);
    let count = iter.count();
    println!("iter.count(): {}", count);

    let _ : Vec<Option<(u64,u64)>> = iter.map(|regex_match| {
        let retval = retention_spec_to_pair(regex_match);
        println!("precision_opt: {:?}", retval);
        retval
    }).collect();
```

The issue is that the `count()` method moves `iter` and I can no longer use it.

```
src/bin/whisper.rs:147:42: 147:46 error: use of moved value: `iter`
src/bin/whisper.rs:147         let _ : Vec<Option<(u64,u64)>> = iter.map(|regex_match| {
                                                                ^~~~
src/bin/whisper.rs:144:21: 144:25 note: `iter` moved here because it has type `regex::re::FindCaptures<'_, '_>`, which is non-copyable
src/bin/whisper.rs:144         let count = iter.count();
```

This does not make sense to me. Should the `count` method just return a copyable `usize` value and not move `iter`? How can I work around this issue?

Comment: If you just need one set of captures, then use `retention_matcher.captures(ts)`. Its contract appears to exactly match your use case. (Indeed, your regex is completely anchored, so it could only ever produce one match for a particular string.) No need to muck around with iterators. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that you're thinking of `iter` as being an abstract sequence of captures.  It is more accurate to think of it as representing a *position within* an abstract sequence of captures.  The basic thing any iterator knows to do is advance to the next item in a sequence; that is, you can advance the position and get the next element in the sequence.

`count` moves `iter` because in order to count how many elements are in the sequence, it has to generate the whole sequence.  This *necessarily* modifies the iterator by stepping it through the whole sequence.  It moves because after calling `count`, the iterator really isn't useful any more.  By definition, it must be past the end of the sequence!

Sadly, it doesn't look like the iterator type in question ([`FindCaptures`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.FindCaptures.html)) is `Clone`, so you can't just make a copy of it.

The solution would be to restructure your code to *not* call `count`.  If you want to get the first element and ensure there are no more, the simplest pattern would be:

```rust
let mut iter = ...;
if let Some(regex_match) = iter.next() {
    // Ensure that there is no next element.
    assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);

    // process regex_match ...
}
```